# dplyr lag function returning NA using ungrouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I am encountering unexpected behavior when using the lag function in dplyr 1.07 after verifying that data are ungrouped. Previous questions about this issue have identified grouping as the root cause for NA returns.

I understand that I can use the diff function as a potential workaround, but wondering if this is a true bug or a problem with how I am specifying the order_by variable.

To replicate:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(grouping = paste0('G', gear,'C',carb)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(qsec_change = qsec - dplyr::lag(qsec, order_by = 'grouping'))
```

Sample output:

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb grouping qsec_change
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     G4C4          NA
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     G4C4          NA
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     G4C1          NA
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     G3C1          NA
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     G3C2          NA
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     G3C1          NA
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4     G3C4          NA
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2     G4C2          NA
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from `order_by = 'grouping'` e.g. `order_by = grouping`

Comment: The argument supplied to `order_by` should not be quoted.  Even fixing that, I'm unable to replicate your issue using `dplyr 1.1.2`.

Comment: I also was unable to replicate your sample output using `dplyr 1.1.1`. Using your code with unquoted "grouping", the values returned for "qsec_change" were -2.14 0.56 3.20 NA -2.99 0.78 -2.16 1.10 2.90 1.28 0.60 0.35 0.20 0.40 2.14 -0.16 -0.40 0.86 -4.38 0.43 -0.21 -0.15 0.43 -2.01 -0.25 -1.00 -2.20 0.20 -2.40 1.00 -0.90 0.08

Comment: Removing quotes from 'grouping' solved this problem in dplyr 1.07 - per comments above, the issue seems to be fixed in dplyr 1.1.1.